# Locating Drivers for Intel AX200 Wireless on 5.1 Kernel

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, elementary-os, intel, iwlwifi

I recently purchased a new laptop which features an Intel Wireless-AX200 Networking device for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth connectivity. I installed elementary OS 5.0 "Juno" along with the latest stable linux kernel (5.1.1), as I've heard that it should come with support for the aforementioned [networking device](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-WiFi-6-AX200-Cyclone-Peak)

However, I cannot seem to find any drivers related to the device, either within `/lib/firmware` or within the 5.1.1 source (looking for anything prepended with "iwlwifi").

Looking through `lspci` reveals the following devices, none of which appear to be a wireless or bluetooth device:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 20 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a334 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a328 (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f10 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f9 (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ada (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1adb (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
05:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
06:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
45:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
```

Has anyone been able to locate these aforementioned drivers within the 5.1 or 5.1.1 source? I've also just emailed linuxwifi@intel.com, and can update this post with their response as it comes in.

**UPDATE**

I received a response from Intel. The driver itself has not made it into the kernel, therefore they suggested using their backport driver (which has now made wi-fi accessible on my laptop [mid-2019 Razer Blade])

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release & [Here](https://eur01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgit.kernel.org%2Fpub%2Fscm%2Flinux%2Fkernel%2Fgit%2Fiwlwifi%2Flinux-firmware.git%2Fplain%2Fiwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode&data=02%7C01%7C%7C84a89b6c77634284883408d6d710e0f3%7C84df9e7fe9f640afb435aaaaaaaaaaaa%7C1%7C0%7C636932864819868763&sdata=RAf5P7Vb0KIeWXrj5LcXTDKE8AmVETZf6BW2gETRRaE%3D&reserved=0)

Comment: Hi Jon. That last bit is an answer, so you should add it as an answer to your question. Not as part of your question.

Comment: Please post your "Update" as an actual answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update:

The driver has been released for [all major kernels here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html?productId=189347&localeCode=us_en)

---

#### Original:

According to the [product page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/wireless/wi-fi-6-ax200-module-brief.html) it's a pre-certified solution and the driver has not been published yet.

Even Linus's Development branch doesn't [reveal anything](https://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=AX200&fold_case=auto&regex=false&context=true) so I'm assuming that **at the time of this writing**, it's not Linux compatible *yet* and the article you're referring to uses marketing speak for: *We'll be adding that soon...*

Answer (score 7):

Just upgrade to the latest Linux Kernel, >5.1, and use the latest firmware for the Wireless adapter:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html