# RTL8723DE [10ec:d723] Wifi card not working on Linux mint 19.2 Tina

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, realtek

I followed [this stack post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547224/rtl8111-8168-8411-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04) its not working for Linux mint.

Tried to install [rtl8723de](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de) driver but returns error

```
$sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms
...
$git clone -b 4.10-down https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
$sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
$sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=4.15.0-66-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-66-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

My network card

```
$lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
```

sudo lshw -class network gives

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: ac:e2:d3:7d:2b:76
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:125 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

-

```
$ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:e2:d3:7d:2b:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.15/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 84388sec preferred_lft 84388sec
    inet6 fe80::3866:d5e2:5cf7:7430/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is my default network interfaces

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Here is the driver install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r8168-dkms is already the newest version (8.045.08-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

-

```
$ uname -a
Linux XXX-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Your title is wrong and you cloned the wrong repo. Your ethernet card is the rtl8111/8168/8411 and your wifi is the RTL8723DE [10ec:d723].
Please read the instructions of your linked driver and try again. There are two instructions "if your kernel is lower than 4.11" and "If you have kernel 4.11 and newer" and you have tried the first one, but your kernel version is 4.15. You need to clone the repo with `git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it shows, ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-32-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: Thanks bro for correcting me.Googled and it worked https://askubuntu.com/questions/961299/cannot-see-my-wifi-10ecd723-when-trying-ubuntu

Comment: The above link worked for Ubuntu but this one worked for linux mint https://subinsb.com/install-realtek-d723-wifi-driver-linux/